# Test failing only in headless chrome

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, headless, wdio-v4

I have some integration tests using wdio, they are all passing. However, when I run them in headless chrome, one of these tests fails. I get this error:

```
1) Reset password by submitting a new password "before all" hook:

element ("#identifierNext") still not existing after 15000ms
```

The problem is in this line of code:

```
browser.waitForExist('#identifierNext');
```

Which is weird, because I am using the `waitForExist(<element id>)` in other tests as well and they pass even in headless chrome. I also tried to increase the `waitFor` limit up to 30000ms, but it fails anyway.

This is my wdio config:

```
exports.config = {
    specs: [
        './test/pageobjects/**/reset_password.spec.js'
    ],
    maxInstances: 1,
    capabilities: [{
        maxInstances: 1,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1280,800', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']
        }
    }],
    sync: true,
    logLevel: 'silent',
    coloredLogs: true,
    deprecationWarnings: true,
    bail: 0,
    screenshotPath: './errorShots/',
    baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    services: ['selenium-standalone'],
    framework: 'mocha',
    reporters: ['spec'],
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 30000
    },
}
```

When I remove `headless` from `chromeOptions`, this test passes normally. Any ideas why this happens?

EDIT: this is my reset_password.spec.js file:

```
describe ('Reset password by submitting a new password', function(){
  //test fails in this before function
  before(function(){
    browser.url(ResetPassword.token_url(valid_email, email_password));
  });

  it ('Password reset without passwords', function(){
    .
    .
    .
  })

});
```

And my reset_password.page.js file:

```
const Page = require('./page');

class ResetPassword extends Page {

  get email() {
    return $('input[type="text"]');
  }

  get url() {
    return browser.getUrl();
  }

  open() {
    super.open('/reset-password');
  }

  get signIn(){
    browser.waitForExist('*=Sign in');
    return $('*=Sign in');
  }

  get enterEmail(){
    browser.waitForExist('input[type="email"]');
    return $('input[type="email"]');
  }

  get submitEmail(){
    //this fails in headless mode
    browser.waitForExist('#identifierNext');
    return $('#identifierNext');
  }

  get enterPassword(){
    browser.waitForExist('#password > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input');
    return $('#password > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input');
  }

  get submitPassword(){
    browser.waitForExist('#passwordNext');
    return $('#passwordNext');
  }

  get tokenEmail(){
    browser.waitForExist('span[email="profiq.ldap@gmail.com"]');
    return $$('span[email="profiq.ldap@gmail.com"]');
  }

  get tokenURL(){
    browser.waitForExist('a[id*=reset_link]');
    const links = $$('a[id*=reset_link]');
    return links[links.length-1].getAttribute('href');
  }

  token_url(email, password){
    browser.url('https://www.google.com/gmail/about/#');
    this.signIn.click();
    browser.switchTab(browser.getTabIds()[1]);
    this.enterEmail.setValue(email);
    this.submitEmail.click();
    this.enterPassword.setValue(password);
    this.submitPassword.click();
    this.tokenEmail[1].click();
    browser.pause(3000);
    return this.tokenURL;
  }

}

module.exports = ResetPassword;
```

Comment: Past here the whole `reset_password.spec.js` here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Gmail displays differently in different browsers. I took a screenshot using `browser.saveScreenshot('screenshot.jpg');` just before the test fails, and it shows that the page looked different (was in my local language instead of english and had different appearance and buttons). So this is the reason why the test could not find the button with given identifier.